# VBA for Excel misbehaving... doesn't return the right value

Tags: vba, excel

I have the following function in my worksheet...

`Format(Range("AG1"), "mm")`

I'm using it to auto-populate the saveas filename, which is a larger function, but it all works except for this part.  As part of that larger function there is

`Year(Range("AG1"))`

which is returning the correct year in "yyyy" format.  (It doesn't require any specific formatting, it just returns the year in 4-digit format.)

However, the first function, `Format(Range("AG1"), "mm")` is always returning 01, indicating that is is January, which it isn't always.  I need the month based on the current date to be returned in "mm" format.

The `Range("AG1")` refers to a cell in the worksheet that has a date entered as `[mm/dd/yyyy]`.

Any ideas what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Are you using English/American/etc regional settings, or something else?  (I think some of the other regional versions of Excel, use something other than "mm" for month)

Comment: Can we see what is in cell AG1?  I just tried this code on my own data and it seems to work fine.  What happens when you try to format the whole date using a single `Format` call like this:  `Format(Range("AG1"), "yyyy-mm-dd")`?

Comment: Also try temporarily setting cell AG1 to be General format, and see whether it becomes a number such as 42866 - just to make sure we are dealing with a valid date.

Comment: The day part of your data in AG1 wouldn't happen to be 1 by any chance?

Comment: @YowE3K - Yes, "$-en-" format...  and I tried to Generalize it, to no avail...

AG1 just contains a date, in date format "mm/dd/yyy"

Comment: What does `?range("ag1").value2` return from the VBE's Immediate window? (use Ctrl+G to get the Immediate window) [edit] and you **really** should specify a parent worksheet unless in a private worksheet code sheet.

Comment: If changing the cell to General format in Excel didn't change the cell to display a number, you haven't got a date in the cell - you just have something that looks like a date.  But, even so, `Format(text_that_looks_like_a_date, "mm")` should implicitly convert the text to a `Date` prior to the formatting, so I'm not sure why it wouldn't work.

Comment: @Jeeped - it returns 42826

Comment: If you put `04/02/2017` into AG1, does your function now return 2?  And is your locale set to use "dd/mm/yyyy" format?  If you have text in the cell, and Excel can interpret it as a valid dd/mm/yyyy date, it will. If it can't, it will try to interpret it as a mm/dd/yyyy date.

Comment: I think you nailed it @YowE3K. Strictly a DMY vs MDY issue.

Comment: "mm/01/yyyy" format being used here...

Comment: ... and yet it is returning **1** as the month ... curious. Edit your question to include several examples of dates; both with amigous day/months and without. Show the results you are receiving and state what you want to receive.

Comment: @Jeeped - but that doesn't **really** explain it, does it?  If `Value2` is returning 42826, then it is a date of 1 April 2017 in the cell.  The difference between `Value2` and `Value` shouldn't affect things if the OP is in a  mm/dd/yyyy locale and is displaying in mm/dd/yyyy format.  I always get confused with this stuff!

Comment: @Matteo - just to confirm ... `"mm/01/yyyy" format being used here` - you mean that your computer is set to a mm/dd/yyyy date display format, not just that that cell within Excel is formatted as mm/dd/yyyy?

Comment: @YowE3K - It is hard to say. Without several examples of dates and what they are producing I am simply using Occam's razor to determine the root cause. If he is getting Jan from 04/01/2017 (e.g. 01-Apr-2017) then it seems to be logical that  it is somehow a DMY.

Comment: Just for the record.... it is a little late for an April Fool's joke.

Comment: @Jeeped - That comment had me laughing for the last 20 seconds - people will start noticing that I am not working when I should be!

Comment: Ok, I'm not sure what happened, but it's working as intended.  I think maybe I wasn't checking the right output filename.  Regardless, thanks to all and I'll post the final code down below...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's the final code that worked for me...

```
Private Sub btnCreate_Click()
  ActiveSheet.Copy
  Application.ExecuteExcel4Macro "show.toolbar(""Ribbon"",False)"
  ActiveSheet.Shapes.Range(Array("btnCreate")).Select
  Selection.Delete
  ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs "C:\Users\" & (Environ$("Username")) & "\Desktop\" & "Timecard, " & Year(Range("AG1")) & "-" & Format(Range("AG1"), "mm") & " - " & _
    Range("R2").Value & ", " & Range("T2").Value, xlOpenXMLWorkbookMacroEnabled
  ActiveWindow.Close
End Sub
```

Comment: I'd recommend that you change `Year(Range("AG1")) & "-" & Format(Range("AG1"), "mm")` to be `Format(Range("AG1"), "yyyy-mm")` - just for readability reasons.

Answer (score 0):

According to this table you should be using "m"

```
No. Formatting code Display as      Example
1   ddd             Weekday name    Sat
2   dddd            Weekday name    Saturday
3   mmm             Month  name     Jan
4   mmmm            Month name      January
5   m               Month           1
6   d               Day             17
```

Comment: `mm` is intended to return the month, with leading `0` if less than 10.  And `dd` is intended to return the day, with leading `0` if less than 10.

Comment: @MiguelFebres The problem is not the date format (returning "01" instead of "1"), but that it is returning the wrong number ("01" instead of anything)